# How do you turn string value to all caps in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to get the popup text for the attack message into all caps, including pre-existing strings from the strings.xml

```
val playerString = getString( R.string.player )
val monsterString = getString( R.string.monster )

val playerHitMonster = Toast.makeText(this, "$playerString HIT $monsterString FOR $playerDam!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

Is there a way to convert the `playerString` and `monsterString` into all caps? ( i.e., "Minotaur" to "MINOTAUR" )

Comment: did you try this method  `playerString.toUpperCase()` ?

Comment: Whilst I did not downvote I suspect the downvote because this should have been easy to answer with a quick Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert the String to All Caps just use this :

```
yourString = yourString.toUpperCase()
```

and for lower case use :

```
yourString = yourString.toLowerCase()
```

Comment: Awesome! this works perfectly. Thank you for your help! Should probably change it form a `val` to a `var`.

Comment: yes according to your needs if you want to display this string only one time you can just use `playerString.toUpperCase ()`

Comment: Note those methods are going to be [deprecated](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/04/kotlin-1-5-0-rc-released/#locale-agnostic-upper-lowercase) and superseded by `.uppercase()` and `.lowercase()` in Kotlin 1.5 as current implementation might produce unexpected result depending on platforms locale.